# “It is happy for me to ....” and “It is glad for me to....”

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, compound-adjectives

Okay, so my students in Japan keep using

> “it is happy for me to…”  “…it is glad for me to…”

I know it is incorrect and the words *happy* and *glad* can be changed with others to make some sentences work, i.e. “it is interesting for me to…” I know *glad* and *happy* are emotions and state of being that need human or animal subjects, i.e. “I am happy for you”.

Also I know that ‘happy feelings’, ‘happy memories’, ‘happy birthday’ are all a different form of the adjective usage. I need help with, what is exactly the issue with “it is happy for me to…”? I can't think of anything other than it is not right, and I feel weird about it. 
So please help!

**Edit:** Native speaker, MA in Linguistics, living in Japan long enough to forget English. Posted here only after the other native speakers failed to answer as well.

Comment: Hi Lucy, are you a Japanese expert in English or a native English speaker? Knowing which one you are might affect the way in which people respond.

Comment: "It makes me happy to see children playing" or "It makes me glad to . . . " are idiomatic and say what your students are trying to say.

Comment: Probably the most common phrasing of the idea "it is [expression of positive emotion] for me to..." in U.S. (and perhaps also British) English would be "it is a pleasure for me to..."

Answer (score 1):

*It is interesting for me to ... .*

is equivalent to

*I find it interesting to ... .*

Similar equivalences are found with adjectives such as *useful /helpful / difficult / annoying / relaxing*.

These adjectives describe the characteristics of some object or action. For example: *a warm bath is relaxing*.

> - It is relaxing for me to have a warm bath when I get home from work.
> - I find it relaxing to have a warm bath when I get home from work.

This doesn't work for adjectives that describe emotional states: *?a warm bath is happy*.

> - ?It is happy for me to have a warm bath when I get home from work.
> - ?I find it happy to have a warm bath when I get home from work.

Comment: Curious usage of ["it is happy to be"](https://www.google.it/books/edition/An_Extract_of_Law_s_Serious_Call_to_a_De/L03LQwZ2pOEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22it+is+happy+to%22&pg=PA82&printsec=frontcover)  So, *It is happy to have a warm bath*... might have been acceptable in the 19h century.